# Css positioning the pseudo element at the start of the div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to position this pseudo element at the start of the cell as shown in the  picture.
[image]

But this is dependent on the number as i use the below the css to achieve this

```
.warning-div:before
  { 
    content: " \26A0";
    position: relative;
    left: -56px;
    top: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
```

It fails when the number length changes as shown below
[image]
[image]

HTMl: It is a normal  tag.

```
<td class="warning-div">7,900</td>
```

Can anyone point out fundamentals I'm missing out here to achieve the icon always in the start.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you share the html code as well?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I have edited the qs.

Comment: I have updated my answer. you ca either increase and decrease the number if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position absolute to pseudo element, and position:relative to the parent. 
Hope this is what you need.

```css
.warning-div{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.warning-div:before
  { 
    content: " \26A0";
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="warning-div">
7000
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `justify-content:space-between;` this will have a space between both elements with proper distance.

```css
.warning-div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.warning-div:before {
  content: " \26A0";
  left: 5px;
  top: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="warning-div">
  7000000
</div>
```